# How are the River, Vimana and Sthala Vruksha appropriately associated with respective temples?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, temple

The divyadesams of Vishnu has a connection comprising River, Vimana and Sthala vruksha. Example God Ranganathaswamy of Srirangam temple has cauvery as river, Vimana is Ranga Vimana and Sthala Vruksha [Tree in the temple] is Vilvam.  Likewise for other divyasesams.  Ancient Siva temples also has  River, Vimana and Sthala Vruksha. 
Any scriptural references how the  river, vimana and sthala vrukshas are rightly associated to the respective temples.

Comment: Most kshetra have sthala purana associated with them. Skanda purana has sthala-mahatmyam of many kshetras

Comment: The comments have created an unnecessary controversy.  The question is unambiguous. It seeks know scriptural evidence how the river, vimana and sthala vrukshas are rightly associated to the respective temples. The question is neither unambiguous nor unclear. I would replace the word 'evidence' with the word 'reference', if it makes the question clearer. The question pertains to Hinduism and its temples and is neither opinion based nor inappropriate on this site. Accordingly, I edit the question replacing the word evidence. THE QUESTION IS UNAMBIGUOUS AND CLEAR.

Comment: @SureshRamaswamy Reference why I mentioned is that this may be mentioned in any puranas. The question is clear as per me. Carefully worded sentences.